# How to hide or show widget built inside FutureBuilder based on daynamic changes

Tags: flutter

Am able to show and hide the widget i want but it keeps flickering or rebuilding its self every time.
i just want to show the the capture icon button when the compass degree reaches 190 degree

> this is my main widget

```
late List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: CameraApp(),
    );
  }
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  String? imagePath;
  XFile? imageFile;
  late CameraController controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  int? angleResult;
  bool showCaptureButton = false;
  String? getLocation;
  bool k = false;
  
 





  void getAngleFromCompass(newResult) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        angleResult = newResult;
      });
    });
  }

  void getLocationRes(newResult) {
    getLocation = newResult;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      cameras[0],
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
    );
      _initializeControllerFuture = controller.initialize().then((value) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _captureImage() async {
    await takePicture().then((filePath) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imagePath = filePath;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Widget cameraWidget(context) {
    var camera = controller.value;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var scale = size.aspectRatio * camera.aspectRatio;
    if (scale < 1) scale = 1 / scale;
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: scale,
      child: Center(
        child: CameraPreview(controller),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
```

theCompassApp(getAngleFromCompass) keeps flikering here

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                cameraWidget(context),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: LocationApp(getLocationRes),
                ),
                Align(
                  child: CompassApp(getAngleFromCompass),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Color(0xAA333639),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                       angleResult == 190 ? IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => _captureImage(),
                          iconSize: 40,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.camera_alt,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ) : Text(''),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

> Compass App Widget

```
    class CompassApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final  getAngleValue;
  CompassApp(this.getAngleValue);

  @override
  _CompassAppState createState() => _CompassAppState();
}

class _CompassAppState extends State<CompassApp> {
  bool _hasPermissions = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchPermissionStatus();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Builder(builder: (context) {
          if (_hasPermissions) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: _buildCompass()),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Text('');
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildCompass() {
    return StreamBuilder<CompassEvent>(
      stream: FlutterCompass.events,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
            child: Text('Error reading heading not support'),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        double? direction = snapshot.data!.heading;
        int ang = direction!.round();
```

> Compass angle passed to main widget here

```
          widget.getAngleValue(ang);


        if (direction.isNaN)
          return Center(
            child: Text("Device does not have sensors !"),
          );

        return Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 41),
                  child: Text(
                    '$ang',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 50,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black26),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _fetchPermissionStatus() {
    Permission.locationWhenInUse.status.then((status) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() => _hasPermissions = status == PermissionStatus.granted);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Should it be like ` future: _initializeControllerFuture(),`?

Comment: _initializeControllerFuture is just for camera initialization  _initializeControllerFuture = controller.initialize()

Comment: i think you kept calling `getAngleFromCompass` inside buildMethod. while UI changes it flicker and next flicker occurs from `addPostFrameCallback` and it has `setState` then again flickers, that's what i think in this case.

can you share the full widget. so that i can test with different future.

Comment: I have edited the question to full code check it out

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Visibility` or `Opacity`?

Visibility

```
Visibility(
        visible: true, //false for invisible
        child: Text('I am visible'),
      ),
```

Opacity

```
Opacity(
        opacity: 1.0, //0.0 for invisible
        child: Text('I am visible'),
      ),
```